# How to Remove leading zeroes from a float value Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Given the `Float` price 0.33, I want to remove the leading zero and decimal so that i can display it as 33 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply it by 100.

```
0.33 * 100 = 33
```

If it is a string. i.e. "0.33" then,

```
if let float = Float("0.33") {

    let cents = float * 100

    let centsStr = "\(cents)" // equals "33"
}
```

If you had a case of multiple decimal places then just round this way.

```
if let float = Float("0.332123") {

    let cents = Int(round(float * 100))

    let centsStr = "\(cents)" // equals "33"

    print(centsStr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the price by 100 and cast it to an `Int` to get rid of fractions of a cent. If you want rounding then its slightly more complicated.

Let's say `price = 3.335`

Then do

```
if (price*1000 %10 >= 5) {
    price = Int(price * 100 + 1)
}
else {
    price = Int(price * 100)
}
```

The `else` part is all you need to do if you don't care about rounding the last cent.

Comment: You could just cast it to a double, and then use the round(), then cast it back to int.

Comment: @TristanBeaton Yeah haha that would probably be easier. I wasn't aware there is a round() function for doubles.

Comment: Its also available for floats as well. You'll be able to see that in my answer. It is a pretty clever way of rounding that you have come up with.